# Karate logging is not working after adding cucumber reporting maven dependency. Log starts displaying once the dependency is removed

Tags: karate

Added method for generating cucumber html report in TestParallel class. But after using cucumber-reporting dependency logback-test.xml file has no effect.

dependency used in pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Log file added under class path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
  
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>target/karate.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>    
   
    <logger name="com.intuit.karate" level="DEBUG"/>
   
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
  
</configuration>
```

Comment: refer this thread please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2436